# l want to add function in python turtle graphics

Tags: function, turtle-graphics

My code lets the user input the turtle count. Then, it will show the amount of input with random turtle shapes and colors. I want to add 3 functions to my turtle graphics code.

1. "Please enter the number of turtles: "
2. Function to initialize the turtle array by receiving the number of turtles as a parameter
3. Finally, the function draws the turtle

Please help me,
here is my code:

```
import turtle 
import random


myturtle,tx,ty,tcolor,tsize,tshape=[None]*6
shapelist=[]
playerturtles=[]
swidth,sheight=500,500


if __name__=='__main__': 
    turtle.title('Turtle list utilization')
    turtle.setup(width=swidth+50,height=sheight+50)
    turtle.screensize(swidth,sheight)
    shapelist=turtle.getshapes()
    a=int(input('Turtle Count:'))

    for i in range(0,a):
        random.shuffle(shapelist)
        myturtle=turtle.Turtle(shapelist[0])
        tx=random.randrange(-swidth/2,swidth/2)
        ty=random.randrange(-sheight/2,sheight/2)
        r=random.random();g=random.random();b=random.random()
        tsize=random.randrange(1,3)
        playerturtles.append([myturtle,tx,ty,tsize,r,g,b])

    for i in range(0,a):
        myturtle=playerturtles[i][0]
        myturtle.color((playerturtles[i][4],playerturtles[i][5],playerturtles[i][6]))
        myturtle.pencolor((playerturtles[i][4],playerturtles[i][5],playerturtles[i][6]))
        myturtle.turtlesize(playerturtles[i][3])
        myturtle.goto(playerturtles[i][1],playerturtles[i][2])
    turtle.done()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using `global` variables. You should consider switching from global variables in this function and it would be interesting and important to read about [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) variables.

```
import turtle
import random

myturtle, tx, ty, tcolor, tsize, tshape = [None] * 6
shapelist = []
playerturtles = []
swidth, sheight = 500, 500


def start_turtles():
    global shapelist
    turtle.title('Turtle list utilization')
    turtle.setup(width=swidth + 50, height=sheight + 50)
    turtle.screensize(swidth, sheight)
    shapelist = turtle.getshapes()
    a = int(input('Turtle Count:'))
    return a


def turtle_start(a):
    global myturtle
    global tsize
    global tx
    global ty

    for i in range(0, a):
        random.shuffle(shapelist)
        myturtle = turtle.Turtle(shapelist[0])
        tx = random.randrange(-swidth / 2, swidth / 2)
        ty = random.randrange(-sheight / 2, sheight / 2)
        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()
        tsize = random.randrange(1, 3)
        playerturtles.append([myturtle, tx, ty, tsize, r, g, b])


def turtle_draw(a):
    global myturtle
    for i in range(0, a):
        myturtle = playerturtles[i][0]
        myturtle.color((playerturtles[i][4], playerturtles[i][5], playerturtles[i][6]))
        myturtle.pencolor((playerturtles[i][4], playerturtles[i][5], playerturtles[i][6]))
        myturtle.turtlesize(playerturtles[i][3])
        myturtle.goto(playerturtles[i][1], playerturtles[i][2])
    turtle.done()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = start_turtles()
    turtle_start(a)
    turtle_draw(a)
```